# py2exe and disappeared icon

Tags: python, pyqt, py2exe

I am using pyqt, icon is added.

```
icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("favicon.ico")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
```

In setup.py for py2exe, I am trying to add my icon to resources.

```
from distutils.core import setup 
import py2exe 
setup(
    console=[{
            "script" : "manage.py",
            "icon_resources": [(1, "favicon.ico")]
    }],
    options={
        "py2exe" : {"includes" : ["sip",]}
    }
)
```

When I start my program from IDE as python script, I see my icon.
When I create exe program with py2exe, my program works well, but icon dissappears.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that py2exe doesn't include the qt icon reader plugin.
Data_files parameter added.

```
from distutils.core import setup 
import py2exe 
setup(    
    options={
       "py2exe" : {"includes" : ["sip",]}
    },
    data_files = [
      ('imageformats', [
        r'C:\programs\Python271\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\imageformats\qico4.dll'
        ])],
    console=[{          
       "script" : "manage.py"       
    }]
)
```